# Regression Discontinuity in Time (RDiT)

Tags: econometrics, regression

Is it correct to specify an RD model where time is the running variable but the data is not measured at the time the running variable is referencing to?

Let's say I want to estimate the impact of a policy implemented in June 2018 that affects labour market entrants. The running variable would be time and people would be ordered in time based on their month of entry to the labour market. So observations in May 2018 are people who entered the labour market in May 2018 but whose data is measured at a different point in time (e.g. July 2019). Is this correct?

My data limitation is that I only have two cross-sections that are measured after the policy is implemented.

What would be the right model based on my data limitations?

Comment: To me this sounds like a DiD defining groups based on labor market entry